# Is AWS SQS the right choice for tasks with hierarchical relationships?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

At this moment I use a simple table in the database to store all my tasks. Every task has the following structure:

```
class Task:
    id: int
    parent_id: int
    priority: int
    command: int
    arg: str
    status: int
```

In short, there is a typical task queue that's stored as a table in DB. Now, I think to use **Amazon Web Services SQS** as more suitable and professional solution (also it's a requirement of my customers). However, in the database I could just check `status` of a parent task and if it was completed or failed then to execute a child task. Is it possible in **Amazon Web Services SQS** or I've chosen a wrong service for my problem? What's a right way to make it if it's possible?

**P.S.** If it's important I use **Python 3.9.5** with **boto3** to access **AWS**.

Comment: If your decision to execute a child task depends on some earlier, related parent task's status then you're still going to need to persist the status of that parent task, probably in a database. SQS might be a sensible place to communicate the list of tasks that need to be performed (and then deleted from the queue) but a queue is not the right place to persist data.

Comment: @jarmod, thank you! However, is there a some way to solve this problem for **SQS**? Even if it's a dirty solution, I still need to know it to explain for customers clearly: what is pros and cons.

Comment: There's really not enough information here. If you know all the potential child tasks for a given parent tasks at the time that you enqueue the parent task then you could simply include the child tasks as children of the JSON object representing the parent task. When that parent task is pulled from the queue for processing, it would have the array of (potential) child tasks attached to it, and you could decide at that point whether or not to process those child tasks.